# Containerize a conda environment in a Singularity container

Tags: conda, hpc, singularity-container

I've come across several instances where it would be really helpful to containerize a conda environment for long-term reproducibility. As I'm normally running in high-performance computing systems, they need to be Singularity containers for security reasons. How can this be done?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

First, you'll want to get the environment YML for your particular conda environment.

```
conda activate your_env
conda env export > environment.yml
```

Here's an example Singularity recipe (in file named 'Singularity' in same directory as 'environment.yml'):

```
Bootstrap: docker

From: continuumio/miniconda3

%files
    environment.yml

%post
    /opt/conda/bin/conda env create -f environment.yml

%runscript
    exec /opt/conda/envs/$(head -n 1 environment.yml | cut -f 2 -d ' ')/bin/"$@"
```

Build this with

```
sudo singularity build conda.sif Singularity
```

Now, you'll have a functioning container using libraries from your conda environment that can be run anywhere you have Singularity installed!

Example:

```
singularity run conda.sif ipython
```

Notes:

Depending on the version of Singularity you're using, you may need to alter $(head -n 1 environment.yml | cut -f 2 -d ' ') with the name of your environment.

Since you can't activate the environment from the runscript, you'll be restricted to binaries installed in your particular environment with the provided runscript.

Comment: I tried and after the "run" I get this error:

`singularity run conda.simg conda -h`
`head: cannot open 'env.yaml' for reading: No such file or directory`

Comment: @AndreaT. It's an issue with the echo "source activate $(...)" > ~/.bashrc command not being executed properly. You could hard code the result of the head/cut command and retry.

Comment: @compBio Thank you, this works decently if I have root access. Any idea whether there is a workaround if I am only a local user?

Comment: @ATpoint Singularity has a 'fakeroot' feature that may solve your issue. Though, I'm not as familiar with that. Ex. 'singularity build --fakeroot /tmp/test.sif /tmp/test.def'

Comment: @LucasBoatwright Thanks for your helpful answer. But I have a problem with running conda env in the container. I commanded `singularity shell conda.sif | conda activate my_env` and got error `CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'`. Do you have any clue about this?

Comment: @RossyClair Did you also try running 'source activate my_env'? The commands required for running 'conda activate my_env' don't get added to the ~/.bashrc when running the above (see 'conda init'). And they can't be added after the fact since the container is read-only.

Answer (score 6):

Using [conda-pack](https://conda.github.io/conda-pack/) it is possible to containerize existing conda environments without re-creating them from `environment.yml`. This is particularly useful when the environment doesn't resolve anymore, or when packages have been installed into the environment without conda, e.g. using `R`'s `install.packages`.

1. pack the environment

   ```sh
   conda-pack -n <MY_ENV> -o packed_environment.tar.gz
   ```
2. create this `Singularity` file

   ```
   Bootstrap: docker

   From: continuumio/miniconda3

   %files
       packed_environment.tar.gz /packed_environment.tar.gz

   %post
       tar xvzf /packed_environment.tar.gz -C /opt/conda
       conda-unpack
       rm /packed_environment.tar.gz
   ```
3. build the image

   ```
   singularity build --fakeroot <OUTPUT_CONTAINER.sif> Singularity
   ```

For more details, including a Docker/Podman variant, check out my [grst/containerize-conda](https://github.com/grst/containerize-conda) repository.

**Limitations**: The approach probably only works if the source environment is on a linux x64 machine.

Answer (score 5):

I have found it useful because you can have a container with anaconda3 environment installed and easily create new Environments for your different projects whenever you want.

This is simple and I will go over it step by step:

1. Create the container in your local machine by the following definition file (you can name it whatever you want. Note that some lines might be avoidable ):

   ```
   Bootstrap: library
   From: ubuntu:18.04
   Stage: build

   %post

   apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade
   apt-get -y install \
   build-essential \
   wget \
   bzip2 \
   ca-certificates \
   libglib2.0-0 \
   libxext6 \
   libsm6 \
   libxrender1 \
   git
   rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
   apt-get clean
   #Installing Anaconda 3 
   wget -c https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2020.02-Linux-x86_64.sh
   /bin/bash Anaconda3-2020.02-Linux-x86_64.sh -bfp /usr/local
   #Conda configuration of channels from .condarc file
   conda config --file /.condarc --add channels defaults
   conda config --file /.condarc --add channels conda-forge
   conda update conda
   #List installed environments
   conda list
   ```
2. Then, in order to build the container, run the following commands:

   ```
   sudo singularity build ContainerName.sif YourDefineFile.def
   ```
3. Now you can create your conda env(you can use common ways or create it by YML file which is an exported file from an existing environment)

   For example, I did it with a YML file:
   First, you need to get into your .sif container as following:

   ```
    Singularity shell YourContainerName.sif
   ```

   And then:

   ```
    conda env create --name envname --file=YourEnvironments.yml
   ```
4. Therefore, After your env is created, you can activate it with the following commands(again first you need to jump into your container):

   ```
   singularity shell YourContainer.Sif

   source activate YourEnvName
   ```